# как реализовать notifyDataSetChanged у другом DataAdapter

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть активность и два дата адаптера, которые отвечают за разные действия. Мне нужно реализовать notifyDataSetChanged одного адаптера в другом.
Вот код для лучшего понимания:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
DataAdapterForChat adapter = new DataAdapterForChat();
ArrayList<String> chat_msgs = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> whoSent = new ArrayList<>();

public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.codes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    editor.putString("Code", holder.codes.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString(("chatName"), snapshot.child("chats").child("NameOfChats")
                            .child(holder.codes.getText().toString()).getValue(String.class));
                    editor.apply();
                    chat_code = holder.codes.getText().toString();
                    chat_msgs.clear();
                    time.clear();
                    whoSent.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot data: snapshot.child("chats").child("List_of_chats").child(chat_code).getChildren()) {
                        chat_msgs.add(data.child("textMessage").getValue(String.class));
                        time.add(data.child("time").getValue(String.class));
                        whoSent.add(data.child("userName").getValue(String.class));
                    }
                    adapter.setter(chat_msgs, time, whoSent);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //тоже не работает
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
            Log.e(TAG, holder.codes.getText() + "");
        }
    });

}

public class DataAdapterForChat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<com.alphabetas.agroup.ViewHolderForChat>{
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> whoSent = new ArrayList<>();
String login, chat_code;

public DataAdapterForChat(){
}

public DataAdapterForChat(Context context, ArrayList<String> messages2, ArrayList<String> time
        ,ArrayList<String> whoSent, String login) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.messages = messages2;
    this.time = time;
    this.whoSent = whoSent;
    this.login = login;
}

public void setter(ArrayList<String> message, ArrayList<String> time, ArrayList<String> whoSent){
    this.messages = message;
    this.time = time;
    this.whoSent = whoSent;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // не обновляет
}
```

}

Ошибок никаких нету, дебаг показал, что данные передаются, из-за notifyDataSetChanged не работает. Спасибо.